# Warning: Missing argument?

Tags: php, post

I have a form HTML and in the php code i have that:

```
function Users($user, $pass, $name, $email){
   if( empty($user) ) return false;
   if( empty($pass) ) return false;
   if( empty($name) ) return false;

   if( empty($email) ) return false;
   $queryr = "INSERT INTO users (Username, Password, Name, Email) VALUES ('".$user."', '".base64_encode($pass)."', '".$name."',  '".$email."')";
}
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    if( QUsers(isset($_POST[$user])) && (isset($_POST[$name])) && (isset($_POST[$name])) && (isset($_POST[$email]))){
         mysqli_query($sqlc2,$queryr);
         if ( isset($_SERVER['username'])){
            echo '<div id="errorUsername">Error</div>';
         }else{
            $_SERVER['username'] = $user;
         }
    }else{
         echo '<div id="ErrorUsername">Error</div>'; 
    }
}
```

And in the moment of view the result, i see that:

```
Warning: Missing argument 2 for QUsers(), called
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cause you are passing only one argument to the function on calling

```
QUsers(isset($_POST[$user]))
```

so try to define all set to blank

```
function QUsers($user='', $pass='', $name='', $email=''){
```

or pass all arguments when calling the function

or try to change your condition to

```
if( QUsers($_POST[$user],$_POST[$name],$_POST[$name],$_POST[$email])){
```